How to persist Redux authentication state using cookies for protected routes after page reload?
I have a MERN stack application with the following setup:

Authentication Flow:


On successful login, a token and userRole are saved in cookies.
I use Redux for managing authentication state (isAuthenticated, user), which is verified in my ProtectedRoute component.


Problem:


After logging in, I am redirected to the dashboard. However, if I reload the page, the Redux store resets, causing the app to redirect to the login page (/) due to the ProtectedRoute logic.
I want to persist the authentication state by verifying the token and userRole from cookies with the backend after every page reload to maintain security and user session.


Code Details:


App.js: Manages the routes for the app.

import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import useUserRoutes from "./routes/userRoutes";
import useAdminRoutes from "./routes/adminRoutes";

function App() {
  const userRoutes = useUserRoutes();
  const adminRoutes = useAdminRoutes();

  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        {userRoutes}
        {adminRoutes}
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;


ProtectedRoute: Handles route protection based on Redux state.

import { Navigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

const ProtectedRoute = ({ children, admin }) => {
  const { isAuthenticated, user, loading } = useSelector((state) => state.auth);

  if (loading) return <div>Loading...</div>;

  if (!isAuthenticated) {
    return <Navigate to="/" replace />;
  }

  if (admin && user?.role !== "admin") {
    return <Navigate to="/" replace />;
  }

  return children;
};

export default ProtectedRoute;


Redux Slice: Manages user state.

const initialState = {
  user: null,
  isAuthenticated: false,
  loading: true,
};

export const userSlice = createSlice({
  initialState,
  name: "userSlice",
  reducers: {
    setUser(state, action) {
      state.user = action.payload;
    },
    setIsAuthenticated(state, action) {
      state.isAuthenticated = action.payload;
    },
    setLoading(state, action) {
      state.loading = action.payload;
    },
  },
});


API Query: Fetches user details (/me) for verifying cookies.

export const userApi = createApi({
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: "/api/v1" }),
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getMe: builder.query({
      query: () => "/me",
      transformResponse: (result) => result.user,
      async onQueryStarted(args, { dispatch, queryFulfilled }) {
        try {
          const { data } = await queryFulfilled;
          dispatch(setUser(data));
          dispatch(setIsAuthenticated(true));
        } catch (error) {
          console.error(error);
        }
      },
    }),
  }),
});


Expected Behavior:


On page reload, the app should:


Extract token and userRole from cookies.
Verify the token with the backend.
Update Redux state based on the backend response.


This ensures users are authenticated without needing to log in again.


Questions:

How can I verify cookies with the backend and persist Redux state on page reload securely?
What is the best way to implement this in my current setup?
Additional Details: I am already using redux-toolkit and react-router-dom. Let me know if more details are needed.

There are several options available to you for persisting the state, but they depend on what exactly you need to store and when exactly you need it referenced again when the app loads. Can you [edit] to share the Redux store code and your authentication code so readers can see what token and user data you are referring to and where/how it's currently stored and accessed? Please also narrow the focus of your post to one specific topic/issue/problem, i.e. either the "verify cookies with the backend" problem or the "persist Redux state on page reload securely" problem.
